# Algebraic equations

Tags: calculus

Given the tensor components

$({\partial}_{x_1}a_1 - {\partial}_{x_2}a_0,\quad {\partial}_{x_1}a_2 - {\partial}_{x_2}a_1 , \quad {\partial}_{x_1}a_3 -{\partial}_{x_2}a_2 , \quad {\partial}_{x_1}a_4 -{\partial}_{x_2}a_3)$

How can show that

${\partial}_{x_1}a_1 -{\partial}_{x_2}a_0 =3({\partial}_{x_1}a_3 - {\partial}_{x_2}a_2)$

and

${\partial}_{x_1}a_4 -{\partial}_{x_2}a_3 =3({\partial}_{x_1}a_2 - {\partial}_{x_2}a_1)$

Answer (score 0):

That is false. Consider $a_0=x_2$ and $a_1=a_2=a_3=a_4=0$. The fact that $a_i$ are components of some tensor is irrelevant.